# Docker not starting on CentOS server

Tags: docker

I installed docker on a CentOS server but it failed while starting.

Below is the error which i got after typing `systemctl start docker`

> Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe"
>   for details.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAKSK.png)

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status docker.service` and `journalctl -xe`?

Comment: How did you install docker? Via yum? What version does it say is installed?

Comment: installed it using yum and 7.4 was installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me too faced the same error and below worked for me.

Edit the `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-machine.conf` file
Change the `ExecStart` to be `/usr/bin/dockerd` instead of `/user/bin/docker daemon`, restart the `systemctl daemon-reload`, and run `sudo systemctl -f start docker` again.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough only today we started having this issue with our dev env. Our version of docker that was provisioned wasn't pinned, and it looks like the most recent version available (1.13.1-53.git774336d.el7.centos) is causing problems as per your question. Targeting a previous version seems to get it back into a working state:

```
yum install docker-1.12.6-71.git3e8e77d.el7.centos
```

Be sure to remove the previous version first

```
yum remove docker
```

Answer (score 0):

It Worked for me:

```
yum remove containerd
```

And remove previous docker and reinstall docker < of course >